# Firebase Authentication updating user profile without permission

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, android-permissions

Users are able to select a photo from their device's gallery when they update the profile photo. The app request permission before the user select photo. But the problem is, when a user uninstalls the app and installs it again they won't see their profile photo anymore because they need to allow the permission once again. I used this code to update the user profile photo:

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    
    val userPhoto: CircleImageView = findViewById(R.id.userImage)

    if (requestCode == OPEN_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val imageUri = data?.data
        userPhoto.setImageURI(imageUri)

        var user = Utils().getCurrentUser()
        val profileUpdates: UserProfileChangeRequest =
            UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setPhotoUri(imageUri)
                .build()
        user?.updateProfile(profileUpdates)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("ProfileChange", "User profile updated.")
                Log.d("ProfileChange","${imageUri}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat ouput is :`D/ProfileChange: content://media/external/images/media/19344`

Is there any solution so users don't have to accept any permission to see their profile photos after they uninstall and reinstall the app?

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: So you want to accept once, and use it for future app installs, right?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution so users don't have to accept any permission to see their profile photos after they uninstall and reinstall the app.

Unfortunately, there is no way you can preserve permissions on an app uninstall. Once an app is uninstalled, everything that is related to the app goes away, including the local cache and permissions. So you need to accept permissions on every new app install.